# assertQueued failing in Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: php, laravel, docker, phpunit, bitbucket

As it says in the title, assertQueued is failing in my Bitbucket pipeline, but it doesn't fail locally.

The test in question can be seen below:

```
Mail::fake();
Queue::fake();

/*Generating users and triggering emails*/

$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user){
    Mail::assertQueued(Email::class, function ($mail) use ($user) {
        return $mail->hasTo($user->preferred_email);
    });
}
```

It simply creates users, sends emails to those users and then checks to see if those emails have been queued.

The phpunit.xml file sets the environment variables as seen below:

```
<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
<env name="DB_DATABASE_API" value="homestead"/>
<env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="log"/>
<env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="database"/>
```

All of this works locally. However, when running it all through Bitbucket pipelines, the test above fails by saying:

```
The expected [App\Mail\Email] mailable was not queued.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

The email is below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Email extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $email;
    public $subject;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param $email
     * @param $subject
     */
    public function __construct($email, $subject)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject($this->subject)->view('contact.emails.email');
    }
}
```

Queueing the email:

```
Mail::to($user->preferred_email)->queue(new Email($user->preferred_email, $subject)));
```

The docker image being used is **PHP:7.2-fpm**. The following is installed:

- git
- curl
- libmcrypt-dev
- default-mysql-client
- zip
- unzip
- composer

**Composer install** and **artisan migrate** are both run before PHPUnit is run. All tests pass aside from that single test. No other tests make use of the assertQueued assertion. Database related tests work without issue and a test making use of `assertSentTo` for a notification that uses the Queueable trait passes without issue.

If you require any further information, please let me know! I appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you add your code where you are sending the email perhaps?

Comment: Added those changes now @DelenaMalan. I'm changing class and variable names to anonymize it, so if there's anything funky, let me know and I'll correct it!

Comment: Just checking: are the users created in the same test method as where you check `assertQueued`?

Comment: Yes they're created earlier on in the test.

Comment: Two questions:
1) Does `Mail::assertSent()` instead of `Mail::assertQueued()` passes?
2) Does changing queue driver to sync has any effect in phpunit.xml?
 `<env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>`

Comment: Can we see the full test? I think it is related to that.

Comment: As stated before i wanna see the full test, i believe it's either there is extra users there is not cleaned up before the test is running or you are utilising the mail facade in a way where the fake() will not pick it up. But imo there needs to be more interaction, as Vladan also has some good points.

Comment: @Vladan your suggestion of looking into the QUEUE_DRIVER led me down a rabbit hole that has now resolved the issue. It seems like I was on a strange version of PHPUnit\Laravel or something like that because upgrading everything resolved the issue. 

Feel free to put an answer up and I'll reward the bounty! Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that your package versions are up to date. It could be some weird hiccup with Bitbucket Pipelines, it knows to do that from time to time.